# issue `object Foo { val 1 = 2 }` in scala

Tags: scala, methods

I found this issue of scala: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4939

Seems we can define a method whose name is a number:

```
scala> object Foo { val 1 = 2 }
defined module Foo
```

But we can't invoke it:

```
scala> Foo.1
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found.
       Foo.1
```

And we can invoke it inside the object:

```
scala> object O { val 1 = 1; def x = 1 }
defined module O
scala> O.x
res1: Int = 1
```

And follow will throw error:

```
scala> object O { val 1 = 2; def x = 1 }
defined module O
scala> O.x
scala.MatchError: 2
    at O$.<init>(<console>:5)
    at O$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
```

I use `scalac -Xprint:typer` to see the code, the `val 1 = 2` part is:

```
<synthetic> private[this] val x$1: Unit = (2: Int(2) @unchecked) match {
    case 1 => ()
}
```

From it, we can see the method name changed to `x$1`, and only can be invoked inside that object.

And the resolution of that issue is: **Won't Fix**

I want to know is there any reason to allow a number to be the name of a method? Is there any case we need to use a "number" method?

Comment: More discussion in the mailing list linked from the ticket: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/k57U6jt8Za0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no name "`1`" being bound here.  `val 1 = 2` is a pattern-matching expression, in much the same way `val (x,2) = (1,2)` binds `x` to 1 (and would throw a `MatchError` if the second element were not thet same).  It's allowed because there's no real reason to add a special case to forbid it; this way `val` pattern matching works (almost) exactly the same way as `match` pattern-matching.

Comment: That makes sense, but it's strange that a `val` with the name `x$1` is being created.

Comment: Implementation detail.  The case where a val binds exactly one name is special-cased so you don't get a `Tuple1` (does that even exist?), but the case where it binds not-one gets a (semi-)anonymous value to hold the results.  Try `val hd::tl = List(1,2)` and you'll see a similar `x$1` be created to hold a tuple which the "hd" and "tl" accessors access.  In the `1 = 1` case the "holder" is a "Tuple0" i.e., `Unit`.

Comment: +1 this is probably expected behavior for programmers in functional languages, less so for people with an OOP background. Btw, Haskell behaves in the same way. `test x = (x, 1) where (x, 1) = (1, 2)` compiles, but fails when trying to call `test 2` with exception `Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (x, 1)`

Comment: That is indeed a difference to `match` handling.  I'll edit my answer to modify the "exactly" when comparing the two.

Answer (score 4):

There are usually two factors in this kind of decision:

1. There are many bugs in Scalac that are much higher priority, and bug fixing resources are limited. This behavior is benign and therefore low priority.
2. There's a long term cost to any increases in the complexity of the language specification, and the current behavior is consistent with the spec. Once things start getting special cased, there can be an avalanche effect.

It's some combination of these two.

---

*Update*. Here's what seems strange to me:

```
val pair = (1, 2)
object Foo
object Bar

val (1, 2) = pair     // Pattern matching on constants 1 and 2
val (Foo, Bar) = pair // Pattern matching on stable ids Foo and Bar
val (foo, bar) = pair // Binds foo and bar because they are lowercase
val 1 = 1             // Pattern matching on constant 1
val Foo = 1           // *Not* pattern matching; binds Foo
```

If `val 1 = 1` is pattern matching, then why should `val Foo = 1` bind `Foo` rather than pattern match?

*Update 2*. Daniel Sobral pointed out that this is a special exception, and Martin Odersky recently [wrote the same](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-debate/msg/f13b2b612b0f8a93).

Comment: `val Foo = 1` as well as `val \`foo\` = 1` are the exceptions to allow normal binding to these identifiers.

Comment: @Daniel To me, it seems most consistent to not do a pattern match if the expression is a single identifier. I.e., broaden the "exception" uniformly.

Comment: @KiptonBarros: 1 is not an identifier, and we want 1 to be pattern-matching in `x match { case 1 => ... }`. It seems that to have uniformity under current rules, val 1 = x must be interpreted as pattern-matching. I think instead one could forbid pattern matches which bind _no variables_ in 'val' statements, and this would also forbid `val Seq() = expr`, which could be replaced by `assert (expr == Seq())`, as `val 1 = expr` is equivalent to `assert(expr == 1)`.
[I'm ignoring on purpose the fact that `assert`s can be elided, one could have a non-elidable assert if desired].

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few examples to show how the LHS of an assignment is more than just a name:

```
val pair = (1, 2)
val (a1, b1) = pair // LHS of the = is a pattern
val (1, b2) = pair // okay, b2 is bound the the value 2
val (0, b3) = pair // MatchError, as 0 != 1
val a4 = 1 // okay, a4 is bound to the value 1
val 1 = 1 // okay, but useless, no names are bound
val a @ 1 = 1 // well, we can bind a name to a pattern with @ 
val 1 = 0 // MatchError
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, you can use backticks to escape the name. I see no problem in supporting such names – either you use them and they work for you or they do not work for you, and you don’t use them.

Comment: Backticks don't work for me, is this what you mean? `object Foo { val 1 = 2 }; Foo.\`1\``